# how to use neo4j/graphql in conjunction with nestjs-neo4j to access the neo4j schema directives

Tags: neo4j, graphql, nestjs, cypher, apollo-federation

I am using:

- `nestjs` v9
- `neo4j` v4.5
- `neo4j/graphql` v3
- `apollo server` v4 w/federation
- `neo4jService` from `nestjs-neo4j`

to create a `neo4jGraphqlService` that uses `neo4jService` for most `neo4j` DB interactions.

But I also want to use the `neo4j/graphql` library to access schema directives such as @relationship, @deprecated, etc.

Is this a bad practice? Should I stick to one library? I want the flexibility of creating my own Cypher queries but I also like the convenience of the `neo4j/graphql` doing some of the work. I hope I don't need to show code for this question as it's a question of best practice.

Ok so maybe some code will help you guys understand the question better....this is the code I am trying to create:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Neo4jService } from 'nest-neo4j';
import { Neo4jGraphQL } from '@neo4j/graphql';

import { Neo4jCredentials, Neo4jConnection } from '../neo4j-credentials';

@Injectable()
export class Neo4jgqlService {
  private neo4jConnection: Neo4jConnection;
  private neo4jService: Neo4jService;
  private neo4jGraphQL: Neo4jGraphQL;

  constructor({ credentials, driver, typeDefs }: { credentials: Neo4jCredentials; driver: any; typeDefs: string }) {
    this.neo4jConnection = {
      scheme: credentials.scheme,
      database: credentials.database,
      host: credentials.host,
      port: credentials.port,
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
    };

    this.neo4jService = new Neo4jService(this.neo4jConnection, driver);
    this.neo4jGraphQL = new Neo4jGraphQL({ driver, typeDefs });
  }

  async dbQuery(query: string, params?: any): Promise<any> {

    return await this.neo4jService.read(query, params);
  }

  ****async dbUpdate(query: string, params?: any): Promise<any> {
     return await this.neo4jGraphQL.****(query, params);
  }
```

So as you can see I have a simple class that instantiate a neo4j instance with both neo4jService and neo4jGraphQL. Now I want the flexibility of the neo4jService especially when I have complex cyphers but for simple cypher where I can use the power of neo4jGraphQL but I can't find any method in the library that allow this. To be precise what would be the proper code here:

```
return await this.neo4jGraphQL.****(query, params);
```

EDIT:   So neo4j/GraphQL V3+ now executes read and write to the DB via the following:

```
const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver 
});
neoSchema.getSchema().then((schema) => {
const server = new ApolloServer({
schema
});
```

So it would seems that Neo4j is using Apollo Server directly to execute the DB read/write but I am not sure whats going on here. Can anyone explain this in the context of my original question?

Answer (score -1):

The `@neo4j/graphql` library allows you to write your own cypher queries, see the `@cypher` directive in the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/type-definitions/cypher/). You may browse the docs to see all the capabilities the lib has to offer. Maybe this helps you to make a decision as I'm not familiar with `neo4jService` from `nestjs-neo4j`.

Comment: Sorry I had to down vote your response...but you should assume from the question that I  am familiar with both.